# Which R plot3D color scheme is suitable for printing?

Tags: r, plot, scatter3d, plot3d

I use `plot3D::scatter3D` function in order to visualize my 3D dataset. Everything works fine, however, the colors that represent the z-level are barely visible when printed (especially yellow).

My code so far:

```
library(plot3D)
require(plot3D)

plot3D::scatter3D(
    rdataset$cores, rdataset$workload, rdataset$speedup,
    xlab='cores', ylab='workload', zlab='speedup',
    theta=320, phi=30
)
```

Could you recommend some cool parameters for `col` and/or `colkey`?

Answer (score 0):

To make points distinct, how is this?

```
library(plot3D)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 50:59, z = 101:110)

plot3D::scatter3D(df$x, df$y, df$z, xlab='cores', ylab='workload',
                  zlab='speedup', theta=320, phi=30,  col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Well, technically it's really readable and printable. However, the demonstration of z-axis is gone as the colors are gone :-(